# finding similar element between two data

Tags: r

I asked a question before which was complicated and I did not get any help. So I tried to simplify the question and input output.

I have tried many ways but none worked for example , I sort down some

# 1

```
for(i in ncol(mydata)){
    corsA  = grep(colnames(mydata)[i] , colnames(mysecond))
    mydata[,corsA]%in%mysecond[,i]}
# here if I get true then means they have match
```

## 2

```
are.cols.identical <- function(col1, col2) identical(mydata[,col1], mysecond[,col2])
res <- outer(colnames(mydata), colnames(mysecond),FUN = Vectorize(are.cols.identical))
cut <- apply(res, 1, function(x)match(TRUE, x))
```

### 3

```
(mydata$Rad) %in% (mysecond$Ro5_P1_A5)
```

#### 4

```
which(mydata %in% mysecond)
```

#### 5

```
match(mydata$sus., mysecond$R5_P1_A5)
```

or

```
which(mydata$sus. %in% mysecond$RP1_A5)

matches <- sapply(mydata,function(x) sapply(mysecond,identical,x))
```

and few others, but none led me to an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using regex:

```
rows<-mapply(grep,mysecond,mydata)
```

The step above will return a list with the matched rows in each column:

```
rows
```

If you would like to see how many rows where matched you can do this:

```
lapply(rows,length)
```

Now we can go ahead a get the rows of interest in mydata, but rows is a list so we need to unlist() and we might have some duplicate rows, and we don't want them to appear twice in the output, so we use the unique() function:

```
rows<-unique(unlist(rows))
mydata[rows,]
#View(mydata[rows,])
```

Comment: @Mol how about now, does that do it?

Comment: everything seems alright but it does not work on my real data. I am really getting crazy , look if you find a way . this is mydata https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0e8865588a01ccaefaf    I load it like this mydata=read.table('~/Desktop/allComplexes.csv',sep=';',header=T,fill=TRUE,quote='')   and this is mysecond https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cbb40d030d7c4d2669db   and I load it like this mysecond <- read.delim("~/Desktop/enriched_proteins.txt")

Comment: Hey @Mol I think I may have got it now, could you please check if that works for you?

Comment: Thank you so much for both your time and your help. is it checking for each column of mysecond and give results for that column or is it for all column ? how does it work? I will defiantly accept your answer even if it won't be my answer but just to appreciate your time. However, I want to know if it is not giving me what I want, then I put more time to get it done

Comment: It's looking for each column in mysecond and checking against every column of mydata, so it gives results for each column, if you remove the unlist() and unique() functions you will be able to see it better. But only accept my answer if it does what you actually want, in case future users have the same question.. but you can always upvote it!

Comment: is it possible to see how many are matched for example for first column of mysecond  and what are they ? I have up voted already

Comment: It is getting much better but there are still some part that does not give right answer. rows<-mapply(grep,mysecond,mydata) I get 50 warning, can I specify a specific column from mydata to be searched ? Mn <- as.data.frame(lapply(rows,length)) gives me the number of matches but does not give me which rows are matched . what this one does rows<-unique(unlist(rows)) can you please add a description to the answer ? and what about this nrow(mydata[rows,])

Comment: @mol I rewrote my answer so it is  more explicit what I was doing, nevermind about nrow(mydata[rows,]), I was just checking we weren't getting back the same orginal dataframe and forgot to remove it from the code.

Comment: I just manually checked the data. it is not right. (you have my data no?) open the mysecond and look at the column Ratio.H.L.normalized.Mo1_P1_A1  it has only 16 element. run Mn <- as.data.frame(lapply(rows,length)) and you see it shows 81 matches , how is it possible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104478/discussion-between-andrelrms-and-mol).

Answer (score 0):

```
require(plyr)
dat <- strsplit(as.character(mydata$subunits..UniProt.IDs.), ',')

dat <- data.frame(mydata[,1],rbind.fill(lapply(dat,function(y){as.data.frame(t(y),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)})))

mydata[unlist(apply(dat,2, function(x) which(x %in% mysecond[,2]))),]
```

Comment: if it is possible, please modify your answer to not be limited to a specific column name but for whatever dimension of data works